# Visual Studio Not debugging for an azure project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012

[image]I am working on Azure project, with Visual Studio ultimate 2013. where my VS in  my project is connected to TFS, but VS is not getting debugged.

We don't have any process to be attached. Tried different ways like clearing bin and rebooting, changing Import & Export settings..

Can anyone please suggest any settings need to be done further.

Any help is very much Thankful.

Comment: Which project are you working on? If you aleady have published your project in TFS  to Azure. Then the debugging is not  related to TFS any more.

Comment: Maybe TFS is not the issue.., but need to do some settings in VS..